# Why is it wobbling in Sonic Pi?

Tags: ruby

I made an algorave with Sonic Pi and ended up with the following code at the end of the session: https://gist.github.com/algorev/2ff2e5d11819cc3620753f3ef2237239
my question is: why is it wobbling? I know I mistyped something and ended up with the second note in the growl pattern being f53, but still, why does it cause the synth to wobble instead of creating a very high-pitched note?
What in the composition of the synth causes this? Or is it caused by another thing in my code?

Comment: Was this a bug or did you find the reason?

Comment: I know what error i did to end up with this, but i don't know why it made this sound.